# JBoss EAP 5.1 - JBossGenericPrincipal

Tags: jboss, vaadin, jboss5.x, principal, vaadin6

Right now I inherited legacy application to support and I found a very strange thing. The application is Vaadin based app and it is hosted on JBoss EAP 5.1. On JBoss there is configured login-config module  - `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule`. This module works fine and does its job. What would I like to do is how to get access to JBossGenericProncipal which is created by this login module? When I debug app and check session (StandardSessionFacade) I can see that it has a field principal but it is private and there is no way to access this principal.

Do you know how to retrieve this Principal? :)

Thanks in advance!

Kamil

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the class `org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossGenericPrincipal`
you can call the method `getCallerPrincipal()` that returns a `java.security.Principal`

Here's a reference from docjar: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/jboss/web/tomcat/security/JBossGenericPrincipal.html.

There's also a `org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossGenericPrincipal` class, but is not available on JBoss EAP 5.

You can also retrieve the java.security.Principal calling the method `getUserPrincipal()` from `HttpServletRequest`